# The import com.maxmind.geoip2 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, import, geoip

I added to my web project geoip2 using maven but in the code when im trying to use it,  the Import is not working. I can see the jar in maven dependencies but i can't use it.  I need some help.

Comment: Can you show us your pom? Also check that the dependency is correctly included `mvn dependency:list -DincludeArtifactIds=geoip2`.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not a complete answer to your problem, but it's too long for a comment.

I've built a sample project using geoip2. POM is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>geoip</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <name>geoip</name>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
         <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the Java code:

```
package com.test;

import com.maxmind.geoip2.WebServiceClient;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.model.CountryResponse;

public class App {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      int userId = 0;
      String licenseKey = "key";

      WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient.Builder(userId, licenseKey).build();

      CountryResponse response = client.country();

      System.out.println(response.getCountry().getName());
   }

}
```

I can't reproduce your import problem. It works just fine. You can download this test here: [geoip2-test.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19067879/geoip2-test.zip)

Check if you can build your project from command line with: `mvn clean install` 

If so, then maybe it's a misconfiguration problem in your project or IDE. 
It's Eclipse? Try `Maven -> Update Project`. Sometimes this works for me when I add new dependencies that are not immediately detected.

Answer (score 0):

if you use intellij, then first close project and then import project and use auto import for the SBT project.then com.maxmind.geoip2 is resolved.